# How can I search custom file properties using the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

Google Drive allows you to add custom properties to files (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties), but they aren't included in the searchable text.

From https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters:

> `fullText   string   contains   Full text of the file including name, description, content, and indexable text.`

You can only search for exact property matches:

> appProperties has { key='additionalID' and value='8e8aceg2af2ge72e78' }

Is there some other way to search the custom properties?

Example: if I have a file with custom property "tags" and value "active banking urgent", how can I get `files.list` (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) to find this file when I search for "urgent"?

Comment: I found a work-around: duplicate the custom properties into "contentHints.indexableText" using "files.update" (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: Are you able to show in code how you were able to write to the file's "contentHints.indexableText". Unfortunately Google doesn't show any examples in its references

Comment: Using the client-side JS API:

gapi.client.drive.files.update({
            'fileId': fileId,
        }, {
            "contentHints": {
                "indexableText": text
            }
        })

Answer (score 8):

How about theses methods? Unfortunately, it couldn't find the flexible search for `appProperties` using `q`. So in order to achieve what you want to do, I propose the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1

1. Retrieve a list of files which have appProperties using `files/appProperties` as a query parameter.

   - `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files%2FappProperties`
   - Only `appProperties` from all files on Google Drive is retrieved.
2. Retrieve the key "tags" and the value "active banking urgent" what you need by a script.
3. Retrieve files using `appProperties has { key='tags' and value='active banking urgent' }` for `q`.

In this pattern, the usage count of APIs are 2.

#### Pattern 2

1. Retrieve a list of files which have appProperties using `files(appProperties,id,name)` as a query parameter.

   - `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(appProperties%2Cid%2Cname)`
   - `appProperties`, `fileId` and `filename` from all files on Google Drive are retrieved. These parameters are searched as `or`.
2. By a script, retrieve elements with the property of `appProperties`, and retrieve files with the appProperties (key "tags", value "active banking urgent") what you need.

In this pattern, the usage count of APIs are 1.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.